# Remove usage of generic wildcard type code smell

Tags: java, list, sonarqube-scan

Im pretty new to java ,

```
public static List<TableDataObject<?>>  getDbLegObjects(TableProcessingObject processingObject) {
       
        List<TableDataObject<?>> matchinglegobjects = null;

        matchinglegobjects = processingObject.getTableDataObjectsDB().stream()
                .filter(result -> Objects.nonNull(result.getLegKey()))
                .filter(result -> result.getLegKey().equals(processingObject.getLegKeyString()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return matchinglegobjects;
    }
```

the above code gives me a code smell saying "Remove usage of generic wildcard at the first line.( <TableDataObject<?>> ) How would i resolve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your method signature to:

```
public static <T> List<TableDataObject<T>>  getDbLegObjects(TableProcessingObject processingObject)
```

and your list declaration to:

```
List<TableDataObject<T>> matchinglegobjects
```

The ? symbol acts as a wildcard.

Comment: It gives me this error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<FlightTableDataObject<?>> to List<FlightTableDataObject<T>>" on the code below ```matchinglegobjects = processingObject.getTableDataObjectsDB().stream()
                .filter(result -> Objects.nonNull(result.getLegKey()))
                .filter(result -> result.getLegKey().equals(processingObject.getLegKeyString()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());``` after changing the method signature and declaration

Comment: In that case your processingObject.getTableDataObjectsDB() returns values of a wildcard type - from my experience it's better to avoid such return types, always try to be as specific as possible and use wildcards only if you care about calling some method of TableDataObject where the type does not actually matter.